# Guessing Game - how to keep score

Tags: java

Essentially I want to input a scoring system into my guessing game which I have currently built the code is below. Currently when the user guesses the correct number they are told their score which is currently set at 10. What I want to do is have the score set at 10 and each time a guess is incorrect that value is decreased by one. 
I'm also having difficulty implementing a exit function while the user is playing the game. Can you folks suggest how I would go about adding these things into my code? 
Note: I'm doing the guessing game on a server I'll just post the protocol part.

Protocol

```
import java.util.*;

public class KKProtocol {
    int guess = 0, number = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
    int score = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    public String processInput(String theInput) {
        String theOutput = null;

        System.out.println("Please guess the number between 1 and 100.");

        while (guess != number) {
          try {
            if ((guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) != number) {
              System.out.println(guess < number ? "Higher..." : "Lower...");
            }
            else {
              System.out.println("Correct!");
              score = 1;
            }
          }   
          catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number! If you want to Quit just say'Goodbye'");
          }   

        }   



        return theOutput;   
    }
}
```

Comment: `score += 1` or `score = score + 1` adds one to the score.  `score -= 1` or `score = score - 1` decreases it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
if (score > 0 && (guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) != number) {
     System.out.println(guess < number ? "Higher..." : "Lower...");
     score--;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Decreasing the score on a wrong guess:

```
if ((guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) != number) {
  System.out.println(guess < number ? "Higher..." : "Lower...");
  score = score - 1
}
```

To end the game you can do something like this:

```
boolean gameRunning = true;
while (guess != number && gameRunning) {
  String input = scan.nextLine();
  if (input.toLowerCase().equals("Goodbye")) { // check for goodbye
    gameRunning = false;
  } else {
    try {
      if ((guess = Integer.parseInt(input)) != number) {
        ...
```

You can also break the loop with the `break` statement.